# Slice string in java

Tags: java, string, excel

How slice string in java? I'm getting row's from csv, and xls, and there for example data in cell is like

> 14.015_AUDI

How can i say java that it must look only on part before _ ? So after manipulating i must have 14.015. In rails i'll do this with gsub, but how do this in java?

Comment: Just to note, using gsub for this in Rails is massive overkill, you should use split, same as Java.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String s = "14.015_AUDI";
String[] parts = s.split("_"); //returns an array with the 2 parts
String firstPart = parts[0]; //14.015
```

You should add error checking (that the size of the array is as expected for example)

Comment: Could you maybe add a method for actually slicing strings? Or maybe OP could change post title?

Comment: If you truly insist on the `split` method for this, use [`s.split("_", 2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,int%29) to waste less work -- but a perhaps more conceptually correct solution is the traditional `indexOf`+ `substring`.

Comment: Typical a "slice" is something, which shares storage. `split` returns two newly allocated strings.

Answer (score 21):

Instead of split that creates a new list and has two times copy, I would use substring which works on the original string and does not  create new strings

```
String s = "14.015_AUDI";
String firstPart = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("_"));
```

Comment: `indexof` must be changed in `indexOf`

Comment: @Youssef, Thanks fixed

Comment: This is wrong, it returns `AUDI`. Needs to be `String firstPart = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("_")+1);` OP wanted `14.015`

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it

Comment: At least in Java 8, substring creates new strings, see in String.java line 2709ff:  `return isLatin1() ? StringLatin1.newString(value, beginIndex, subLen)
                          : StringUTF16.newString(value, beginIndex, subLen);`

In StringUTF16, line 1179, then for example: `return new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(val, index << 1, last << 1), UTF16);`

Answer (score 4):

```
String str = "14.015_AUDI";
String [] parts = str.split("_");

String numberPart = parts[0];
String audi = parts[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Should be shorter:

```
"14.015_AUDI".split("_")[0];
```

Comment: You do not use any error handling here. Bad. 

In this case it can be acceptable because the split() of an empty string will yield an array with a single empty string, but if you wanted to access element [1], you would get an exception. 

Always check possible errors!!

Comment: This is just an example of operation. If you need more functionality - you have to write your own program.

Comment: Shorter than _what_? If you love the `split` method for this, you should pass a limit like  [`.split("_", 2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,int%29) to save memory and time.

Comment: This is outside of the question. The first rule of optimization - do not optimize. If it is needed - that's another question.

Comment: On this way we can detect JavaScript developer – all should be shorter! ;-) I think it is better because the Java class file is small. Поздравляю с 10000! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Guava has [Splitter](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#Splitter)

```
List<String> pieces = Splitter.on("_").splitToList("14.015_AUDI");
String numberPart = parts.get(0);
String audi = parts.get(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use substring!

"substring(int begIndex, int endIndex)"

eg:

```
String name  = "14.015_AUDI";
System.out.println(name.substring(0,6));
```